# Split object into two properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

a very beginner question below I'm sure, apologies for asking but I've had a good hunt on the matter with no luck... I'm looking to 'break' or 'expand' the following:

```
var words = { hello: 2, there: 3, heres: 1, text: 1 }
```

Into this:

```
var words = [{
  word: 'hello',
  count: 2
}, {
  word: 'there',
  count: 3
}, {
  word: 'heres',
  count: 1
}, {
  word: 'text',
  count: 1
}]
```

I've been messing around a lot with Underscore.js, but must be missing something very obvious. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with `Object.keys()` and `map()`.

```js
var words = { hello: 2, there: 3, heres: 1, text: 1 }
var result = Object.keys(words).map(e => ({word: e, count: words[e]}))
console.log(result)
```

You can also first create array and then use `for...in` loop to push objects.

```js
var words = { hello: 2, there: 3, heres: 1, text: 1 }, result = [];
for(var i in words) result.push({word: i, count: words[i]})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hey @Nenad i am having problem but its actually is reverse of the question asked, can you please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution using `Array#map`.

```js
const words = { hello: 2, there: 3, heres: 1, text: 1 },
      res = Object.keys(words).map(v => ({ word: v, count: words[v] }));
      
      console.log(res);
```

Or `Array#reduce`.

```js
const words = { hello: 2, there: 3, heres: 1, text: 1 },
      res = Object.keys(words).reduce((s,a) => (s.push({ word: a, count: words[a] }), s), []);
          
      console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using underscore's [**map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) function:

```
words = _.map(words, (v, k) => ({word: k, count: v}));
```

Underscore's map can iterate over an object. The first parameter  to the iteratee is the value and the second parameter is the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
let object = {
  "06.10 15:00": 3.035,
  "06.10 21:00": 3.001,
};

let arr = [];

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  arr.push({ date: key, value: value });
}

console.log(arr);
```